# Is there such a thing as directional derivative in single variable calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In multivariable calculus, the directional derivative is described in the following way:

> While hiking in rugged terrain, you might think of your altitude at the point given by
>   longitude x and latitude y as defining a function $f (x, y)$. Although you won’t have a handy
>   formula for this function, you can say more about this function than you might expect. If
>   you face due east (in the direction of the positive x-axis), the slope of the terrain is given
>   by the partial derivative
>   ${∂ f\over
> ∂x}
> (x, y)$. Similarly, facing due north, the slope of the terrain is
>   given by
>   ${∂ f\over
> ∂y}
> (x, y)$. However, how would you compute the slope in some other direction,
>   say north-by-northwest? In this section, we develop the notion of directional derivative,
>   which will answer this question.
>   (Calculus, Early Transcendental Function, 4th ed. Smith and Minton)

Usually the diagram that is given is something like this:[image]

all of which seem to make it very clear that this is a concept in multivariable calculus, such as in $R^3$.

I am wondering if such a concept exists in single variable calculus as well.

If I have a function such as $x^2$, we know how to find the rate of change at a point. But what about the rate of change at a point in the direction of a certain vector? Is there a reason why such a concept would not make sense? 
I have in mind something like this:

[image]

Would it make sense to describe the rate of change at the green point in the direction of the red arrow?

Comment: There are no "$\mathbb R^2$ vectors" in $\mathbb R$. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: **What** $\Bbb R^2$ vector if the domain is $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if such a concept exists in single variable calculus as well.
>
> If I have a function such as $x^2$, we know how to find the rate of change at a point. But what about the rate of change in the direction of a certain $R^2$ vector?

For a single (real) variable function, points of the domain live on the real line, so in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

The only choice you still have, when approaching a point on the $x$-axis, is coming from the left- or the right-hand side. These one-sided derivatives (think about one-sided limits in general) are sometimes called the *left* and *right derivative*. You could see those as the only two possibilities in 1 dimension of the concept of "directions", corresponding to the "(unit) vectors" (in $\mathbb{R}$) $-1$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: One could consider the derivative with respect to any nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}$ (which amounts to a scaling of the $x$-coordinate) - not just the unit vectors.

Comment: That's possible, although it is very common for directional derivatives that the use of a unit vector is required (e.g. in many definitions, though not always), to allow comparing of values/magnitudes (and correct for differences caused by scaling).

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture, would you be able to explain a little more why the picture doesn't make sense?

Comment: The rate of change for a one-variable function is how $y=f(x)$ changes with changes of $x$ (only $x$!). So you can only "move" on the $x$-axis and see what the corresponding $y$-values do. From the $x$-value corresponding to the green dot, you can move to the left, or to the right.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense, so any change in a direction other than $x$ would require a multivariable function.

Comment: Correct! Your suggestion (with the red arrow) would make sense for a two-variable function where your plot only shows the domain and how you want to move from the green point. The directional derivative will give the rate of change of the function value $z=f(x,y)$, which is not on that 2D-plot.