# Does the existence of directional derivatives imply differentiability in a single-dimensional space?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Wikipedia says the following:

> The directional derivative of a scalar function
> $$
> f(\mathbf{x})=f\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right)
> $$
> along a vector
> $$
> \mathbf{v}=\left(v_1, \ldots, v_n\right)
> $$
> is the function $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f$ defined by the limit ${ }^{[2]}$
> $$
> \nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{x})=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h \mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h} .
> $$

Now let us take a scalar function of $x \in \mathbb{R}$. As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175998/is-there-such-a-thing-as-directional-derivative-in-single-variable-calculus), in this case there are only two directional derivatives to be considered - right and left hand side derivatives. Suppose $\mathbf{v}$ in the above limit formula is the unit vector in the right direction. But in the above limit formula, $h$ can approach zero from both right and left. Therefore, for the above limit to exist, the left and right hand side limits must be equal.  Therefore, in the single-dimension, the existence of the above limit for any one direction (right or left) - i.e. the existence of any one directional derivative - should imply differentiability.

Is this reasoning correct? I think I might be missing something and this is not correct.

Comment: Yes, this is all correct. Given you are looking at a two-sided directional derivative, there really is only *one* direction, and (assuming you use unit vectors) its definition is precisely that of a derivative in the single variable case.

Comment: Thank you so much!